# Why subdomain shows the home page not the path configured in the Apache config?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, subdomain

To add `panel` sub-domain, I added an `A` record in the DNS server and now the `panel.lamtakama.com` has ping as well (it didn't have ping before defining that A record).

Also, I've added a new `VirtualHost` in the Apache config file. Here is the full Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName lamtakam.com
        ServerAlias www.lamtakam.com

        ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myweb

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.lamtakam.com [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =lamtakam.com
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/html/myweb>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>                       # ----------- From here down ----------- 
        ServerName panel.lamtakam.com
        ServerAlias panel.lamtakam.com

        ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/panel/public

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And restarted the `apache2`. The issue is, the sub-domain `panel.lamtakam.com` shows me the `lamtakam.com` home page. I mean, it doesn't execute `/var/www/panel/public/index.php` file.

Any idea what's wrong?